# Getting HTML value into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

There is a string value in a p class like `<p id="demo">10 hours : 25 minutes : 20 seconds</p>`. Here I want to split that value like `10:25:20`. This is my javascript function.

```js
function countdownTimeStart(){
   var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

   var x = setInterval(function() {
     something ... 
   }
```

So I need to replace the `var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();` into above `10:25:20` which comes from p tag. I'm tried following way.

```
var countDownDate = document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the *text content* of the element there. `.value` only works for `input`s and `textarea`s.

```js
const digits = document.querySelector('#demo').textContent.match(/\d\d/g);
const time = digits.join(':');
console.log(time);
```

```html
<p id="demo">10 hours : 25 minutes : 20 seconds</p>
```

Comment: Where is the var countDownDate object?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I apply this into var countDownDate, I'm new to the Javascript.

Comment: Just replace `const time` with `const countDownDate` if you want the variable name to be `countDownDate`.

Comment: "not working" does not tell me anything about what the problem is - please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

`div` doesn't have a `value`, it has `innerHTML` and `textContent` which can be get/set

```
var countDownDate = document.getElementById('demo').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById("some");

```
        var x = document.getElementById("some").innerHTML;


</script>
<body>
    <p id="some">Some text</p>
</body>
```